# ReactJs adding active class to DIV

Tags: reactjs

I have 3 DIVs, dynamically created. My target is: when any div is clicked to add active class to it, and of course if any other has that active class to remove it. How can I achieve that?

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles/App.css";
import { Container, Box, Typography, makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  mainBox: {
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "space-evenly"
  },
  mybox: {
    backgroundColor: "#9fa8da",
    padding: "40px",
    color: "#fff",
    maxWidth: 300
  }
});

function App() {
  const clasess = useStyles();

  const [active, setactive] = useState("");

  const mydata = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "Ganesh",
      des: "UI Developer"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Suresh",
      des: "Accountant"
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "Srikanth",
      des: "Digital"
    }
  ];

  const onClick = index => {
    setactive("active");
  };

  return (
    <Container>
      <Box className={clasess.mainBox}>
        {mydata.map((val, index) => {
          return (
            <>
              <Box
                boxShadow={1}
                key={index}
                onClick={e => {
                  onClick(index);
                }}
                className={active}
              >
                <Typography variant="h4">{val.name}</Typography>
                <Typography>{val.des}</Typography>
              </Box>
            </>
          );
        })}
      </Box>
    </Container>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

I have 3 DIVs, dynamically created. My target is: when any div is clicked to add active class to it, and of course if any other has that active class to remove it. How can I achieve that?

I have 3 DIVs, dynamically created. My target is: when any div is clicked to add active class to it, and of course if any other has that active class to remove it. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Need to add active class to div

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to check when active id is the clicked id:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles/App.css";
import { Container, Box, Typography, makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  mainBox: {
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "space-evenly"
  },
  mybox: {
    backgroundColor: "#9fa8da",
    padding: "40px",
    color: "#fff",
    maxWidth: 300
  }
});

function App() {
  const clasess = useStyles();

  const [active, setActive] = useState();

  const mydata = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "Ganesh",
      des: "UI Developer"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Suresh",
      des: "Accountant"
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "Srikanth",
      des: "Digital"
    }
  ];

  const onClick = id => {
    setActive(id);
  };

  return (
    <Container>
      <Box className={clasess.mainBox}>
        {mydata.map((val, index) => {
          return (
            <>
              <Box
                boxShadow={1}
                key={index}
                onClick={e => {
                  onClick(val.id);
                }}
                className={val.id == id ? active : deactive}
              >
                <Typography variant="h4">{val.name}</Typography>
                <Typography>{val.des}</Typography>
              </Box>
            </>
          );
        })}
      </Box>
    </Container>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

You already managed on your Box component to add an "active" classname when one of them is Clicked.

But, you need to add some style or something to show for those "active" elements.

Inside of `useStyle` add the class `active` and test it out with some styling:

i.e)

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  mainBox: {
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "space-evenly"
  },
  mybox: {
    backgroundColor: "#9fa8da",
    padding: "40px",
    color: "#fff",
    maxWidth: 300
  },
  active {
    backgroundColor: "red"
  }
});
```

I'm not sure if you need to add "active" class using `classes`, something like :

```html
             <Box
                boxShadow={1}
                key={index}
                onClick={e => {
                  onClick(index);
                }}
                className={classes.active}
              >
                <Typography variant="h4">{val.name}</Typography>
                <Typography>{val.des}</Typography>
              </Box>
```